# Why does Boinc Manager behave differently than all other windows?

Tags: ubuntu, window-manager, mate-desktop

My laptop is running a standard Ubuntu MATE 14.04 (obsolete, I know, but it's for work so we will upgrade "later"). I've installed Boinc as per the standard instructions, and it's chugging along fine with my SETI account.

But the Boinc Manager window behaves oddly.

1. Whenever I merely hover my cursor over it, the window comes to the front. This only happens when I have enabled "Select windows when the mouse moves over them" (aka. X-Windows focus follows mouse).
2. When I click the "x" button to close the window, it instead minimizes to the *task bar* (in addition to the system tray). I have to explicitly right-click on the minimized task bar button and select "close" from there.

Is this a known thing, or just on my machine? Can I disable this annoying behaviour (no, I can't find a setting for it, neither through the UI nor through my account on the web site)?